# Displaying Array Elements in an *.aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

For some of you, this may seem trivial - but please indulge me as I seem to have a severe mental block in understanding how displaying array elements is possible.

Ok, so here's where I'm at:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestCoding._Default" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent">
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1><%: Title %>.</h1>
                <h2>Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET application.</h2>
            </hgroup>
            <p>
                <asp:TextBox ID="post_feedback" runat="server" Height="100" Width="500" BackColor="#0066FF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FF9933" Wrap="False" TextMode="MultiLine" BorderColor="#000099" BorderStyle="Groove" BorderWidth="2"></asp:TextBox>  
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Count_Sentences" runat="server" Text="Count Sentences" OnClick="Count_Sentences_Click"/>

        <br />
        <br />

        <asp:Label ID="Num_Sentences" runat="server" Font-Bold="true">How Many Sentences Do we have today?</asp:Label>

            </p>
        </div>
    </section>
 </asp:Content>
```

And the Default.aspx.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace TestCoding
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Count_Sentences_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)


        {

            int post_length = post_feedback.Text.Length;

            string[] post_words = post_feedback.Text.Split(' ');
            int num_words = post_words.Length;



            Num_Sentences.Text = post_feedback.Text + " " + Convert.ToString(post_length) + " and has " + post_words.Length + " words." + post_words[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < num_words; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(post_words[i]);
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Ok, so I understand that Num_Sentences is a Label I created in the aspx page - and that on clicking the button, the Count_Sentences_Click routine is called, it does some "stuff" and binds Num_Sentences.Text to a string that's comprised of different strings and other data...

The bit of code after that data binding, which I *intend* to have all the elements in the post_words array be written...but it's not working out so well.

What I have found so far it seems is, "Oh, all you have to do is set up a loop of sorts and just do Console.WriteLine(arrayname[i]) and all will be well with the universe."

Obviously, I am having some problems in understanding how to successfully display the array elements. Do I need a separate Label ID to put this into or what? I'm confused. :P

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` writes to the console. A web page is not the console.

Comment: Look into controls that "repeat" a markup section based on a given collection of items: Repeater, ListView, etc

Comment: Thanks CyberDude - found a solution that works for my purposes. :)